# Count emails by month and year for all folders in a mailbox

Tags: email

I have a mailbox in Outlook. For example ("some_name@a_web_address.com").

The mailbox has many folders and subfolders that contain emails (7 main folders and for example, 1 main folder has 97 subfolders with subfolders).

This setup is not ideal, I understand. But I am looking for a way to count the emails in this mailbox by month and year. For example, a grand total of 500 emails in "some_name@a_web_address.com" for January, 2015. I hope that makes sense.

Is this possible? I am able to create a count for 1 folder at a time. But with so many folders, it is very time consuming. I appreciate any assistance. Many Thanks - Jwal45

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way is to create Search folders in Outlook. See [Create a Search Folder](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/recreate-it-961e78c8-9be5-48b5-b8b1-2c7beebe5b25?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1) for more information.

Also you may consider developing a VBA macro or add-in where you can filter items according to your conditons. The [Find/FindNext](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/) or [Restrict](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/) methods of the Items class from the Outlook object model do the trick.

But the most powerful and reliable search is using the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Application class. See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article in MSDN helpful.